# phpinfo.php is not showing extra folder for additional PHP configuration files

Tags: apache-2.2, php, configuration

My phpinfo.php is not showing extra folder for additional PHP configuration files. I am running Apache v2.4.4(with PHP DSO) and PHP v5.4.14 on CentOS v6.3 32-bit. Apache and PHP installations are compiled from source.

I have not used the configure option `--with-config-file-scan-dir=PATH` for PHP. (And won't be using because I will be needing more than one folder).

Environment variable `PHPRC` and Apache Directive `PHPIniDir` are related to the main PHP file, which leaves me with the Environment variable `PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR` to work with. Below are the steps what I did:

## STEP 1 of 2 - Settings for PHP

`PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR` being an OS Environment variable is required to be set before Apache starts. So I added the following entry to my `/etc/profile.d/php.sh` file.

```
PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR="/usr/local/lib/php/custom"
export PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR
```

Then rebooted the system.

Now the commands `env | grep PHP`, `php -i | grep INI` and `php --ini` give me the following outputs.

=> `# env | grep PHP`

```
PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR=/usr/local/lib/php/custom
```

=> `# php -i | grep INI`

```
PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR => /usr/local/lib/php/custom
_SERVER["PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR"] => /usr/local/lib/php/custom
```

=> `# php --ini`

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/lib
Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/lib/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/lib/php/custom
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

## STEP 2 of 2 - Settings for Apache

**First Attempt**

**===================**

Added the following entry in both apache2/bin/envvars & apache2/bin/envvars-std files.

(**Any comments on what is the difference between envvars & envvars-std file?**)

```
PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR="/usr/local/lib/php/custom"
export PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR
```

Restarted Apache service.
But the value for `Scan this dir for additional .ini files` from **phpinfo.php** file shows empty.

**Second Attempt**

**===================**

So I removed the entries from envvars & envvars-std. I have module **mod_env** loaded by default. I added the following in **httpd.conf**.

```
SetEnv PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR "/usr/local/lib/php/custom"
```

Restarted Apache service.
Value for `Scan this dir for additional .ini files` from **phpinfo.php** file still shows empty.

**Third Attempt**

**===================**

Again, I removed the entries from **httpd.conf**. Added the same line to Directory section of my `VirtualHost` in **httpd-vhosts.conf**.

```
SetEnv PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR "/usr/local/lib/php/custom"
```

Restarted Apache service.
Value for `Scan this dir for additional .ini files` from **phpinfo.php** file still shows empty.

ANSWERS ON SOME OF YOUR THOUGHTS:

- Yes, my **phpinfo.php** file is made of only `phpinfo()`. It is not a static file.
- Yes, the browser cache was cleaned. I also tried another browser.

**Finally**

So, can anyone tell me why my phpinfo file is not showing the extra folder for additional PHP configuration files?

Comment: The feature in question is both undocumented and kind of painful to get working correctly; the better option is to use the compile-time flag for setting this directory; failing that, try using symlinks to manage the configuration instead of changing the path.

Answer (score 2):

You have to start apache with that environment variable set. Setting the variable in `/etc/profile.d/php.sh` only sets it for the PHP executable itself, which is not used by mod_php5.

I just went through this rigamarole. Setting the variable with SetEnv won't work, either, as it's defined after mod_php5 is loaded.

In CentOS 6.5, I found that editing `/etc/sysconfig/httpd` allows you to set and export additional environment variables for the apache process itself. So try adding it there:

`export PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR="/usr/local/lib/php/custom"`